# asp.net disabling listbox on postback

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net listbox. A master-detail view. When the selectionchanges on the listbox, controls on an update panel update. All working fine. Now if the user arrows through the listbox selections I get like a million postbacks. Ideally (for UX) it would be great to cancel the previous postback. But what I tried was on the PageRequestManager.add_initializeRequest: disable the listbox with jquery so the user cannot make another selection. Then on add_endRequest enable the listbox. The boss does not like the disabled look for a couple of seconds.

Can someone think of a better way for me to handle this? I tried changing the color while disabled but could not find a way.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax ModalPopupExtender, you can show a progress bar or simply a spinner icon for informing the user that the server is busy doing his/her last operation. The ModalPopupExtender disable all page controls till finishing the operation.

[This](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx) is the official control page.
And [this](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/modalpopupextender_example_for.html) is an example from Matt Berseth, he uses it for editing but the concept is the same.